# How to delete a RealmList element?

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a class as follows:

```
public class SomeStuff extends RealmObject {

    public RealmList<CatDetails> cat;


    public RealmList<CatDetails> getcat() {
        return cat;
    }

    public void setCat(RealmList<CatDetails> cat) {
        this.cat = cat;
    }
}
```

and here's CatDetails:

```
public class CatDetails extends RealmObject {

    @Index String catNumber;
    @Index String catName;


    // setters and getters for catName and catNumber
}
```

Now how do I go about deleting one element from the field `cat`? That is, I want to reduce the size of the arraylist in the class `SomeStuff` by 1.

I've tried:

```
realm.where(SomeStuff.class).findAll().get(pos).getCatDetails().get(0).deleteFromRealm();
```

as well as:

```
realm.where(SomeStuff.class).findAll().get(pos).getCatDetails().deleteAllFromRealm();
```

But I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when populating the recyclerview in both the cases.

Comment: Well you'll need to add what you're doing with that RecyclerView adapter.... And whether it's a RealmRecyclerViewAdapter, and more importantly what thread you're doing this deletion on

Answer (score 0):

Deletion :

```
realmList.get(0).deleteFromRealm();
```

But it is worth noting that tables get updated immediately inside a transaction, so just using an enhanced for loop doesn't work like it does on a RealmResults. A normal `iterator()` with `remove()` would work instead.